# jQuery Ajax .fail not working on localhost

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, localhost

I have the following Ajax script that puts the input of a form through a process.php.

This works fine, both on localhost and on the server. The .fail callback, however, is only working on the server.

If I stop my Apache Server through XAMPP and try to submit the form, .fail is not being executed.

Am I misunderstanding how .fail works (on a localhost), or is there something wrong with my code?

script.js:

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {

 var formData = {

   'age' : $('input[name=age]:checked').val()

 };

 $.ajax({

   type     : 'POST',
   url      : 'process.php',
   data     : formData,
   dataType : 'json',
   encode   : true

 }).done(function(data) {

   $('section#results').append('<p>Age: ' + age + '</p>');

 }).fail(function(data) {

   alert('failed');

 });

 event.preventDefault();

});
```

process.php:

```
$data['form']['age'] = $_POST['age'];

echo json_encode($data);
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: "If I stop my Apache Server through XAMPP and try to submit the form" , don't do that

Comment: Maybe you just have a long timeout for missing connections...

Comment: Why not test with an exception?  http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.throw.php

Comment: All you have to do to test the `fail()` method in your case is sending anything back that is not valid json.

Comment: You can try with an error header on server side
`header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");`

Comment: This is nothing to do with localhost or not. If you stop your server, you'll more than likely never get as far as the .fail(). Watch your network tab / console in the browser's developer tools. Probably you'll get a connectivity error instead. .fail() is meant for when you get a response from the server, but not the one you were expecting. It's not intended to handle the case where you get no response at all. If you want to test .fail() then your best option is to deliberately create some sort of error condition in your code, so you can see how it flows.